# how can i know the cursor is now focus in input or textarea or select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to run ajax to get a value , if value is true ,then submit the form, the code bellow using onsubmit=xxx , but this form will submit immediately , not waiting ajax result. then I want to using an "a" tag with onclick function to submit the form , this can do the job, but when I using "enter" key to submit the form , will not run ajax codes. then I want to bind keypress when the cursor is in input field to submit the form. how to check the cursor is in or out of the form fields?

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['act'])){
        $rs=array(
            'status'=>0
        );
        echo json_encode($rs);
        exit;
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
    <form onsubmit="return filters.submit()">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var filters={
        form: $('.filters').find('form'),
        submit: function (){
            $.ajax({
                url:'index.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    act:'ajax'
                },
                success:function(rs){
                    eval('var rs='+rs);
                    if(rs['status']==1){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you allow the form submission to just happen, and do whatever AJAX request at the same time in a single request? If you need to do validation, you should bind to the form's `submit` event and conditionally cancel it, but that's typically for client-side validation. I think doing one submission to test whether you can do the second "real" submission is a pretty serious problem in your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rajesh Jinaga said `document.activeElement` return the currently focused element but I want to explain you why it doesn't work.

When you are making your ajax call it won't wait until the ajax return true or false. It will execute. So you need to prevent the form to be submited and submit it with javascript when your ajax call is finished.

**HTML**

```
   <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (jQuery)**

```
   $('form').submit(function (e){

        $.ajax({
            url:'index.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                act:'ajax'
            },
            success:function(rs){
                // No need of EVIL eval('var rs='+rs);
                if(rs['status']==1){
                    $(this).submit(); // Will submit the form.
                }else{
                    alert("FAILED!");
                }
            }
            return false; // Shortcut for e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() so it will prevent the form to be submitted.
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.activeElement` returns the currently focused element, that is, the element that will get keystroke events if the user types any.

Answer (score 1):

$(this).submit() won't work because you are in different context, and success callback invoker send ajax related object but not form DOM object. Store object into a variable in the form context and use it in success callback.

```
 $(function(){
    $('form').submit(function (){
       var form = this;
        $.ajax({
            url:'index.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                act:'ajax',
                status: $('[name=status]').val()
            },
            success:function(rs){
                eval('var rs='+rs);
                if(rs['status']==1){
                    $(form).submit();   // or $('form').submit()
                }else{
                    alert('error');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@L105, thank you for your answer, I modify my code to match your answer , but the form can not submit using $(this).submit();

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['act'])){
        $rs=array(
            'status'=> $_POST['status']
        );
        echo json_encode($rs);
        exit;
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="status" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function (){
            $.ajax({
                url:'index.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    act:'ajax',
                    status: $('[name=status]').val()
                },
                success:function(rs){
                    eval('var rs='+rs);
                    if(rs['status']==1){
                        $(this).submit();   // can't submit
                    }else{
                        alert('error');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have no actod and method please try to add `<form action="something.php" method="POST">` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp OR you ajax call fail.

Comment: Try changing `success` to `always`.

Comment: And you eval does nothing please remove it.

Comment: eval is working , page return json str , I need to make it to an array.

Comment: what is "succcess to always"?

Comment: eval doe nothing, rs is already an array. Your eval is just creating a variable and assign the array o it. It does not convert it. Change the key `success: function(rs) {...}` to `always: function(rs) {...}`.